# apply css style to multiple nodes having the same css class using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, dom

How to set a CSS property to multiple elements having the same class?

***As for my situation:*** I would like to know how to set the `background-image` for multiple elements which has the same class using vanilla JavaScript.

Let's say I have 5 `div`'s, each having a class `.panel`

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="panel">
            <h3>Mesmerizing Mountains</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <h3>The connecticut</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <h3>Spooky forest</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <h3>Wheat fields</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <h3>Alpha Hills</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If i have the links to the images as an array, like this:

```
const imgLinks = ["https://example.com/panel_1img", "https://example.com/panel_2img", "https://example.com/panel_3img", "https://example.com/panel_4img", "https://example.com/panel_5img"]
```

How can i set the `background-image` for each of the `.panel` from the `imgLinks` array.

quick note: The first element in the array should be the `background-image` of the first `.panel`
The second element in the array should be the `background-image` of the second `.panel` and so on.

Comment: Well, in your example you have 5 elements and only three images, so how are the images supposed to be applied?

Comment: @ScottMarcus i wrote them as reference. i do have 5 images in real. Anyway i will edit it now.

Comment: We still need more information, which image is supposed to go with which element?

Comment: @ScottMarcus The first element in the array should be the background image of the first `.panel`
The second element in the array should be the background image of the second `.panel` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `querySelectorAll` to get an array of all elements with the class `panel` and `forEach` to loop through each.

```js
const imgLinks = ["https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif",
"https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif",
"https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif",
"https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif",
"https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif"];

/* images coutesy of w3schools.com */

document.querySelectorAll('.panel').forEach((e, i) => {
  e.style.backgroundImage = `url('${imgLinks[i]}')`;
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel">
    <h3>Mesmerizing Mountains</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <h3>The connecticut</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <h3>Spooky forest</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <h3>Wheat fields</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <h3>Alpha Hills</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this only works for the first `.panel` right?

Comment: @PixieDust I've updated my answer to demonstrate. The previous example only showed one because only one URL in the array actually existed.

Comment: Note that you will need to set the other background rules separately in your css.

Comment: It should be noted that this will not work in IE, as it does not have support for forEach on a NodeList. You will need [a workaround](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/) if you need IE support.

Comment: `.panel` might be used elsewhere, better to hone in on `.container .panel`

Comment: It's okay. I was just doing a mini project in my spare time and i use chrome. Thanks this solved my issue.